# Avoid doubling up margins and padding in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a simple example of something that seems reasonable to me, but that I can't figure out how to model in HTML/CSS.

I'd like to create a fixed-width container in `px` units with padding in `px` units.  Inside, I'd like to display three paragraphs, separated by vertical margins in `em` units.

The width and padding should be in pixels, so I can calibrate to screen size.  The margins should be in text units, so the spacing adjusts to changes in font size.  This all makes sense so far.

[image: Example of desired result]

The problem is, the most obvious HTML/CSS implementation gives me leading and trailing margins I don't want.

[image: Example with undesirable leading and trailing margins]

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div {
            width: 300px;
            padding: 10px;
            border: solid black 1px;
        }

        p {
            margin-top: 1em;
            margin-bottom: 1em;
            border: dotted black 1px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>Paragraph 1</p>
        <p>Paragraph 2</p>
        <p>Paragraph 3</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a good, general way to achieve this without tampering with the margins on the first and last `p` elements?  Obviously, I can suppress those specific margins, but that's not a very scalable solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use :first-child and :last-child on p tag to remove the margin.

```
p:first-child{
        margin-top:0;
      }
 p:last-child{
        margin-bottom:0;
      }
```

Here is the demo: https://codepen.io/NehhaSharma/pen/zYYoQgg

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Actually there is a way, [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-child/) for :first-child and [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/last-child/) for :last-child.

Answer (score 2):

Don't mix padding and margins if you don't want this behaviour. Use margins everywhere and they will collapse.

If the inner box margin is `1em` and the outer box margin is `10px`, the resulting collapsed margin will be `max(1em; 10px)`:

```css
        div.outer {
            width: 300px;
            /*padding: 10px;*/
            border: solid black 1px;
        }
        
        div.inner {
          margin: 10px;
        }

        p {
            margin-top: 1em;
            margin-bottom: 1em;
            border: dotted black 1px;
        }
```

```html
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"> <!-- this div will be used only to simulate padding -->
      <p>Paragraph 1</p>
      <p>Paragraph 2</p>
      <p>Paragraph 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

Reference about collapsing margins:

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)

[CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/what-you-should-know-about-collapsing-margins/)

Comment: I had considered this solution, but I would really prefer the container padding/margin to be a constant `10px` all around.  This solution can yield a top and bottom margin of `1em` instead.  Still, upvoting because this solution may be practically useful in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it using CSS Grid. `link` https://codepen.io/tripti1410/pen/JjjbqmP?editors=1100

Comment: This solution produces the correct result.  However, it does replace the `p` margin with a constant `grid-row-gap`.  This locks us in to a constant gap between elements.  Basically, we have to forgo (vertical) margins entirely inside the `div`, since they no longer collapse properly with the `grid-row-gap` in between.  That's quite a significant trade-off, and I'm not sure the trade-off is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main p {
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border: dotted black 1px;
}

.main p:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.main p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  <p>Paragraph 2</p>
  <p>Paragraph 3</p>
</div>
```